# Making a textbox appear/exist - javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If the user enters a certain word into a text box I would like a second text box to appear on the screen (for them to enter new information). Does anyone know how to do this in javascript or jquery (and if in JQuery what library must I include?)

Comment: what have you tried so far?There is lot of documentation available on net.Search for onkeyUp event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using JavaScript [keyUp event](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeyup.asp), if you would like to make it using jQuery, [this page](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/) is a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is add a onkeyup function to the textbox and inspect the value of the textbox everytime your method is called, based on this value you can then do whatever else is necessary

Answer (score 0):

I will program it up in javascript (which I know quite well but haven't used in a while) using the onkeyup event - I didn't want to reinvent the wheel so thought I'd ask as surely someone has done this before but I realise now from being voted down that stackoverflow is not open to this kind of approach - i.e. you need to put in the time and only if failing ask a question.

I was hoping also for some advice about using jquery which I haven't used much but of course it can be done in javascript